# What will be the equation corresponding to this graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

Here is the image of a graph. It looks much similar to tan(x) graph but it isn't. I mistakenly made this graph while making the graph of tan(x). But I am curious to know that what will be the equation of this graph and how am I supposed to find it?

Comment: It's not a function, look! The vertical line test fails here.

Comment: Maybe you could interpret the three curves as level sets of a surface.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yeah I know that that's why I edited my tag of graph-functions to random-graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is both graphs of $y=\tan x$ and $y=-\cot x$ superimposed, you could achieve this with the implicit function $$(y-\tan x)(y+\cot x)=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much!